# What part of the C standard allows for closures (blocks) in LLVM?

Tags: c, objective-c, llvm

The LLVM C compiler supports "blocks" which are closures e.g.

```
typedef returnType (^MyTypeName)(parameterTypes);
MyTypeName blockName = ^returnType(parameters) {puts("OK");};
```

Is this a part of the C standard or is it just their invention to support Objective-C?

Answer (score 6):

The part of the C standard that allows it is C 2018 4 paragraph 6:

> … A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program.